# Given expected output and partially completed java program related to inheritance. Need help in completion. Constraint-Not to touch main method

Tags: java, inheritance

This question was asked in my recent coding round. Its kind of tricky as we cannot modify getClass() and getClass().getName()

along with main method, Given are Food and FoodFactory class templates.

I had to print the following lines:

```
My name is Fastfood.
My name is Fruits.
Our superclass is Food
I'm serving Fastfood
I'm serving Fruit
```

Code:

```
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class FoodFactory{
public Food getFood(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Food(string);
}

public String toString(){
    return "Food";
}

public static String getName(){
    return "Food";

}
}
class Food{
   String name;
   public Food(String string) {
      this.name = string;
   }
   public void servesFood() {
        System.out.println("I'm serving "+name);

   }
   public String getName(){
       return name;
   }
}


class Solution
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        foodFactory myFoods = new foodFactory();
        Food food1 = myFoods.getFood("Fastfood");
        Food food2 = myFoods.getFood("Fruits");
        System.out.println("My name is: " + food1.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("My name is: " + food2.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("Our superclass is: " + food1.getClass().getSuperclass().getName());
        food1.servesFood();
        food2.servesFood();

    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't wanted to add my incomplete non-working code.. after your comment, I have added my partially working code.. to the question

Comment: After your update I put in an answer that should have enough content to get you going. Please note: I didnt compile/test my input - it is meant as something that you read carefully to understand what is needed; so that you then can create your own solution!

Comment: Besides: let me know if my answer did help (for example by accepting); otherwise let me know what is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing for this exercise is revealed by one word in your example output: **superclass**.

You want that getClass().getName() gives you **different** output. In order to get there, surprise: the objects you call getClass().getName() on ... need to have **different** classes!

Something like

```
class Food {
  public void servesFood(){
    System.out.println("I'm serving Food");
  }
}

class FastFood extends Food {
  @Override
  public void servesFood(){
    System.out.println("I'm serving Fastfood");
  }
  ... similar for Fruit
```

If you now create instances of those two objects, they will give you the expected output. Now the question is: how are instances created?!

That is where your factory comes in:

```
class FoodFactory {
  public Food getFood(String name) {
    switch(name) {
      case "FastFood" : return new Fastfood();
      case "Fruit" : return new Fruit();
      default: return new Food();
    }
  }
```

Please note: the above implementation assumes that any food that is not "Fastfood" or "Fruit"... is real "Food". And of course: you might expect that the actual "name" of the fruit ends up as some field within your Food class, but such refinements/extensions are left as exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you. I some how forgot factory pattern.. as you mentioned.. superclass is clue and I missed to catch even that! Its working now..

Comment: Glad I could help. I hope you don't mind the -3 on your question, as I would hate to loose that 15 rep for answering when you decide to delete your question ;-)

Comment: ha ha.. Not a problem.. :-) I got to know what I was missing.. that's a +10 for me ;)

Comment: And you just got "compensated" ;-) Have a nice day, was great working with you. But, honestly: your question is really borderline to be "poor quality". So, for the next time: time some time studying the help center; to really understand how to write up questions that dont end up in so many downvotes.

Comment: Sure. I will note that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the implementations of the two classes.

```
class FoodFactory{
 private String name;
 public Food getFood(String name){
       this.name = name;
       Food food = new Food(name);
       return food;
 }
 public String getName{
  return name;
 }
}

class Food extends FoodFactory{
private String name;

public Food(String name){
this.name = name;
}

public void servesFood(){
System.out.println("I'm serving "+ name);
}

public String getName(){
return name;
}
}
```

This should work.

Comment: food1.getClass().getName() is not same as food1.getName().. food1.getName() would have executed your public String getName() method.. but when you do food1.getClass() it refers to Food class.. and food1.getClass().getName() refers to name of Food class.. "Food" and not the name of the object..

Comment: Yes. You are right. getName() is a method of Class, which is a final class. So overriding this method is not possible as we can't inherit from Class.

Comment: Sorry pal, you have no idea how to solve this little puzzle. Best would be to delete your answer. You see, you dont have to deal with Class at all. This is all about simple polymorphism; nothing out of the usual here.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work.

```
class FoodFactory extends Food {
    public Food getFood(String string) {
        if (string.equals("Fruit")) {
            return new Fruit("Fruit");
        } else {
            return new FastFood("FastFood");
        }
    }
}

class Fruit extends Food {
    public Fruit(String name1) {
        super.name = name1;
    }
}

class FastFood extends Food {
    public FastFood(String name1) {
        super.name = name1;
    }
}

class Food {
    public String name = null;
    public Food() {

    }
    public Food(String string) {
        this.name = string;
    }
    public void servesFood() {
        System.out.println("I'm serving " + this.name);
    }
}

class Solution1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        FoodFactory myFoods = new FoodFactory();
        Food food1 = myFoods.getFood("FastFood");
        Food food2 = myFoods.getFood("Fruit");
        System.out.println("My name is: " + food1.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("My name is: " + food2.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("Our superclass is: "
                + food1.getClass().getSuperclass().getName());// modification
        food1.servesFood();
        food2.servesFood();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have introduced new classes fruit and fastfood and also made each of them extend food so that we can print superclass Food